# Reactive framework stream switching

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am looking for an extension such as Switch, but instead of defaulting to the most recent stream, I need a switch with an extra variable that can go back and forth based on another external event.

eg. We have observable which is a merger of 2 streams `A` and `B`, when event `C` is detected, I want observable `A` to pass through, and streams from `B` be ignored (lost). When event `D` is detected, I want observable `A` stream to be dropped and `B` be passed through.

What is the best linq operator for this? I suppose I could use a combination of where and some custom solution but really looking for a more elegant solution.

Also I would like to avoid subscribing/resubsribing from the stream where possible. I just find subscribing/resubscribing generally really hard to keep track of, plus hard to chain the operators.

Comment: Are events `C` and `D` inferred from something in streams `A` and `B` or are they external events? And are `A` and `B` the same type?

Comment: @yamen They are external events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways one can tackle this, let's look at a simple one. In this example I assume that events `A` and `B` are of the same type. I also assume that events `C` (tied to `A`) and `D` (tied to `D`) are also observables without any important information.

```
var streamA = new Subject<string>();
var streamB = new Subject<string>();

var switchToA = new Subject<Unit>();
var switchToB = new Subject<Unit>();
```

Now here we open a `streamA` window whenever `switchToA` fires and close it when `switchToB` fires, and do the opposite for `streamB`, then merge them:

```
public IObservable<string> SwitchingWindows(IObservable<string> streamA, IObservable<string> streamB, IObservable<Unit> switchToA, IObservable<Unit> switchToB)
{                                       
    var switchedA = streamA.Window(switchToA, _ => switchToB).Concat();
    var switchedB = streamB.Window(switchToB, _ => switchToA).Concat();

    return switchedA.Merge(switchedB);
}
```

Subscribe:

```
    var all = SwitchingWindows(streamA, streamB, switchToA, switchToB);
    all.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Test:

```
streamA.OnNext("a1");           // skip
switchToA.OnNext(Unit.Default); // switch A
streamA.OnNext("a2");           // shown
streamB.OnNext("b1");           // skip
streamA.OnNext("a3");           // shown
switchToB.OnNext(Unit.Default); // switch B
streamB.OnNext("b2");           // shown
streamB.OnNext("b3");           // shown
streamA.OnNext("a4");           // skip
switchToA.OnNext(Unit.Default); // switch A
streamA.OnNext("a5");           // shown
streamB.OnNext("b4");           // skip
streamB.OnNext("b5");           // skip
switchToB.OnNext(Unit.Default); // switch B
streamB.OnNext("b6");           // shown
streamA.OnNext("a6");           // skip
```

Output is as expected:

```
a2
a3
b2
b3
a5
b6
```

The final stream `all` is 100% clean.

Comment: Quick question though: what's up with the Concat() at the end of the switched observable?

Comment: I've made an edit to make it all much the simpler. The `Concat` is needed because the `GroupJoin` (and now `Window`) functions return each window or buffer as another `IObservable` - so the type of the return is `IObservable<IObservable<string>>`. `Concat` flattens that into `IObservable<string>`.

Comment: even better! I'm very impressed.